# Format code as code in the review preview

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review, code-formatting, markdown-preview

This is what I mean:

When you are in [SO/review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/) as you know you can see answers like this:

[image]

The problem I have is when I see this, I think the code is NOT properly formatted.

So I click on `show full answer`

and get this:

[image]

A well formatted code.

I'm NO expert in most of the subjects discussed in StackOverflow but that shouldn't prevent me from improving the posts in ways I can, for example, formatting code as code.

So, the fact that I can't quickly preview whether code is properly formatted (something crucial to the site experience) means we have to go post-by-post with an extra click to check if the code is formatted.

I think this shouldn't be something very difficult to implement and would significantly improve the review experience.

What do you think about this?

Comment: @studiohack - That's a pretty thanks-less job you're doing there.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128068/mathjax-not-loaded-properly-on-review

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this doesn't qualify as an answer, but this would be awesome. It's a huge pain to keep checking each answer to see if the code is formatted. Please show the code as formatted in the review list so we can more easily edit answers and keep the quality up without wasting time.

#### WE NEED THIS.