# HTML entities are visible in the review page

Tags: bug, status-completed, review

There are visible `&hellip;` entities in the review list page, as seen on the attached screenshot.

[image: Review list]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Format code as code in the review preview](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77278/format-code-as-code-in-the-review-preview)

Comment: To the people voting to close as duplicate, the question linked by Cody is not a duplicate of this, however, if you look at the screenshot in the question, you'll see the `&hellip;` symbols displayed as they should be, as three dots signalling there is more to the answer than can be seen from the review page.

Comment: @Cody, @Banang confirmed, this is not a dupe it is a regression

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was a regression with my port to [razor](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx)

Fixed now

Comment: to be deployed later

Comment: I believe this is broken again -- [see here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98889/why-the-he-do-i-see-so-many-hellips)

Answer (score 0):

The comments seem to be going through an additional url encoding somewhere, so the ellipses are being rendered as literal `&hellip;`. Inspecting the element in Firebug I see: `&amp;hellip;`