# Why the heck do I see so many &hellip;s?

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown

When I go to the `/questions` page of an arbitrary site of the network, the first few lines that are shown of the question body end with a literal `&hellip;` instead of …

[image: hellip]

I'm using Firefox 3.6 on Vista.

Comment: I see them as well on Firefox 5.0 in Ubuntu 11.04.  Someone must've made a typo, switching `&ellipsis;` for `&hellip;`

Comment: @Waffles, you playing with [razor again?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93185/html-entities-are-visible-in-the-review-page/93353#93353)

Comment: Related: [HTML entities are visible in the review page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93185/html-entities-are-visible-in-the-review-page), [Search results aren't rendering properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78597/search-results-arent-rendering-properly), [Question summaries contain visible HTML markup symbols](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78551/question-summaries-contain-visible-html-markup-symbols)

Comment: Most likely, I can see both &amp;hellip; and &amp;lt; in the source on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Marc: Wow, this was quick. If you write an answer, then I can accept it to close the case.

Comment: Since when is `heck/hell` a curse word?!

Comment: @Hendrik - I happened to be doing a build. We watch meta and the error-log pretty closely when we build ;p

Comment: @Bobby: Same as in "Oh my Gosh, this darn computer".

Comment: `status-waffles-did-it`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

M. Tibbits gets alarmingly close to the truth there ;p

One nice thing about razor - if you get it wrong, you end up *double*-encoded, which is much safer that *un*-encoded. "Ugly" trumps "XSS violation" every day of the week.

Fixed.

Comment: Solid reasoning _and_ great dating advice :)

Comment: @Tim oh, but you wouldn't XSS violate someone on a first date...

Comment: The temptation to digress here is _almost_ irresistible.